# Activiti cloud help charts resulting in no Service with the name "activiti-postgresql-headless" found

Tags: activiti, activiti-cloud

I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-full-chart.  I've fixed several problems, but this one is the one I can't get around.
The actual error is:

> release activiti failed, and has been uninstalled due to atomic being
> set: no Service with the name "activiti-postgresql-headless" found

I can't find any helm chart in activiti that has this service mentioned.  Where is this char getting that service from?  (I'm not a Helm chart expert)